# DRF loading binary files sending from React app

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I made a standard API for downloading files to AWS S3. Using the standard DRF interface, the files are loaded correctly into the repository.

**models.py**

```
class Documents(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    upload = models.FileField(storage=PrivateMediaStorage())
    filename = models.CharField(_('documents name'), max_length=64)
    datafile = models.FileField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Doctype, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class DocumentsListView(AwsUrlMixin, viewsets.ViewSetMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Documents.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentsSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, LifeLinePermissions)
    pagination_class = None

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

Problems begin when the download is done through the user interface and the file is transferred using React.

An error occurs in the django console

```
HTTP POST /api/v1/files/ 400 [0.02, 127.0.0.1:33916]
```

In the browser debugger

[image]

**UPD**
\
React code (using library **uppy**)

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem(localStorageNames.token);

    const uppy = Uppy({
      meta: { type: 'avatar' },
      restrictions: { maxNumberOfFiles: 1 },
      autoProceed: false
    });

    uppy.use(XHRUpload, {
      endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/files/',
      fieldName: 'filedata',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `JWT ${token}`
      }
    });

    this.setState({ uppy });
  }



  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.uppy.close();
  }

  clickHandler = () => {
    this.state.uppy.setMeta({
      filename: this.state.form.filename,
      filetype: this.state.form.filetype
    });

    this.state.uppy.upload();
  };
```

Comment: can you show how you are sending request with react as, it might happen that react is not properly sending the file. It's not that django does not accept the format. but the error means that no file is submitted in datafile field. which means you are not sending any file.

Comment: @Eternal I added react code to my question

Comment: As I guessed you are not passing anything to datafile field, the actual file needs to be sent in that field @Jekson

Comment: @Eternal Do you know how to solve this problem??

Comment: I guess you can use this `uppy.setFileState(fileID, {
  xhrUpload: { fieldName: 'pic0' }
})` although I am not that familiar with react

Comment: The guy who makes the frontend just showed me that his code works great with backend written in ruby on rails. So there's still a problem with the django

Comment: The problem is front-end not sending the file into datafile field.